# Configuring IIS without inetmgr

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7, configuration

I have Windows 7 Home Basic on my laptop.

I installed Visual Studio and IIS. I want to use IIS for development purposes. I need to make two things:

1. Mapping the domain name on localhost to the file path where the web files exist.
2. Defining an SSL on the local server
3. Using URL Rewrite

The problem is `inetmgr` is not existing in my IIS directory `c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\`.

Is it possible to make these settings using xml files inside the `config` folder without using `inetmgr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A domain name is not mapped to a file path. A domain name is mapped to an endpoint `binding` for the Web Site, and the root application of that Web Site is mapped to a path on the file system.
   To add a new binding to a web site without using the management console, you can use [`appcmd.exe`](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe). See example 1 below.
2. To enable SSL on a website you need to do 2 things; add an HTTPS binding to a website (just as in step 1), and add an ssl certificate to the corresponding IP endpoint with netsh.exe. See example 2 below.
3. URL Rewrite rules is already defined as XML nodes, see the [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) on IIS.NET

### Example 1: Add a new binding to a website:

```
appcmd.exe set site /site.name:WebSiteName /+bindings.[protocol='http',bindingInformation='*:80:www.mywebsite.com']
```

Where "WebSiteName" is the name of the website, `*:80` is the IP endpoint, and `www.mywebsite.com` is the domain name you wish to use.

### Example 2: Add an ssl certificate to an IP endpoint:

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```

Where `0.0.0.0:443` is the endpoint, the `certhash` value is the certificate thumbprint and the `appidd` is just a random GUID.